# Silverlight MVVM Isolated Storage

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, isolatedstorage

I've tried to use IsolatedStorageSettings in my ViewModel, but these are not getting retained across browser refreshes (F5).

for example;

```
//look in the IsoStore for remembered details


    IsRememberMe = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains(Constants.LOGIN_REMEMBERED_USERNAME);

        if (IsRememberMe)
        {
            UserName = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[Constants.LOGIN_REMEMBERED_USERNAME] as string;
        }
```

Do I need to do something differently in my MVVM ViewModel's??

**EDIT**
It's worth noting that this code is sitting in a referenced project - so ultimately a seperate XAP file to the parent XAP that is loaded in the browser - might this cause the settings to be lost on each refresh?

THanks,
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...

In my case I have issues using Application Isolated Storage, each time I deployed a new version of my app (just for instance changing the color of a button I lost my Iso Storage :-().

I move to use SiteStorage instead of Application level, and it worked:

http://www.tipsdotnet.com/TechBlog.aspx?PageIndex=0&BLID=13

On the other hand what I had done with Iso Storage is perform CRUD on folders and files, not sure abou that other kind of settings.

HTH
     Braulio

Answer (score 0):

I would think one of two things is happening here.  Either your binding isn't working correctly in both directions so either the persistence or the retrieval code is never hit.  Or, you're storing these values in application level iso storage from two different applications (or something to that effect).  Make sure your code is being hit in both cases (storing and retrieving) and make sure you're accessing the iso store from the same place (if you're using application level isolation, store/retrieve from the same application, etc).